# what decimal separators are in use around the world?

Tags: communication

what decimal separators are in use around the world?  (I have a few places between programs where I must exchange a floating point number as a string without a thousands separator.)  yes, I know this isn't a fantastic idea...there are many ways this could be done but more serious improvements will need to come later...

I know of "," and "." but are there any others?

Comment: could just use scientific notation and eliminate the problem. 1.1e3 is far less ambiguous than `1,100` or `1 100`

Comment: You should use `gettext` for such stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

There you have a list of separators (basically ",", "." and " " in writing and also "'" and "˙" for handwriting), with many examples of all of them in different countries.

Since this is applied to programming, you should only worry about ",", "." and " ", that is, unless you are doing some OCR'ing.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecimalPoint.html.  It makes it sound like the decimal point, the decimal comma and the raised period are the only things in use.

You can also check out wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_point but it doesn't really say much else.

Comment: thank you; that's reassuring.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this on .NET environment by looping all CultureInfos framework had (806). The result set was ".", "," and "/". The last one was Persian CultureInfo.